# Separate target IP and WSDL in PHP SoapClient

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

A video encoder I need to query from PHP for status and settings provides a SOAP interface.

The vendor provides a WSDL file which includes 15 schemas with `schemaLocation` naming external URLs. The XSD files are also provided by the vendor.

Since the system must operate without a public internet connection, I modified all of the imports to point to a local url, eg

```
http://localhost/path_to_schemas/xml.xsd
http://localhost/path_to_schemas/settings.xsd
http://localhost/path_to_schemas/inputs.xsd
```

and so forth

How do I use PHP `SoapClient` to query the encoder(s) using the local WSDL and schemas?  Can't find any hints in the PHP documentation or elsewhere online.  Most examples assume the WSDL file will be on the queried device, which in this case its not.

So I tried specifying the WSDL as localhost and put the target machine and namespace in the options:

```
$options = array("location" => "192.168.2.161", "uri" => "http://www.appeartv.com/automation/v1");

$sp = new SoapClient("http://localhost/visor/options/optAppearControl/webgui/be/atvSoapSchema/ATV.wsdl", $options);
$result = $sp->getModuleList();
```

However, this fails with an exception "Unable to parse URL" on the `getModuleList()` line.

Apache error_log:

```
[Sat Nov 10 06:55:05 2018] [error] [client 192.168.2.10] 
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Unable to parse URL
in /usr/local/webgui/be/testSoap.php:16
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('<?xml version="...', '192.168.2.161', 'getModuleList', 1, 0)
#1 /usr/local/webgui/be/testSoap.php(16): SoapClient->__call('getModuleList', Array)
#2 /usr/local/webgui/be/testSoap.php(16): SoapClient->getModuleList()
#3 {main}
  thrown in /usr/local/webgui/be/testSoap.php on line 16
```

Which URL can it not parse?

The [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php) say that:

> *location* is the URL of the SOAP server to send the request to, and *uri*
>   is the target namespace of the SOAP service

I'm a bit confused on what `uri` should be set to.  The "target namespace" in the xsd and wsdl files shows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions 
  xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
  xmlns:tns="http://www.appeartv.com/automation/v1/wsdl" 
  xmlns:atv="http://www.appeartv.com/automation/v1" 
  name="AppearTV_Automation" 
  targetNamespace="http://www.appeartv.com/automation/v1/wsdl">
  <types>
    <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <import namespace="http://www.appeartv.com/automation/v1" 
        schemaLocation="http://localhost/visor/options/optAppearControl/webgui/be/atvSoapSchema/automationInterface.xsd" />
    </schema>
  </types>

  <!-- system.xsd -->
  <message name="getModuleList">
    <part name="foo" element="atv:getModuleList"/>
  </message>
  and so on...
```

So is the target namespace `atv` (as used throughout the xsd files) or `http://www.appeartv.com/automation/v1/wsdl` (as shown in the wsdl file) or `http://www.appeartv.com/automation/v1` (as shown in the xsd files) ??

I've tried all, but all show the same error message.